# Dns & Gate ошибка настройки сети

Tags: gate, dns, шлюз

Возможно задам глупый вопрос.

На своем шлюзе пробовал настроить сетевое подключение, во внешней сети у нас есть DNS сервер и шлюз на разных машинах (пусть шлюз будет 20.10.0.2, DNS 20.10.1.3 картина примерно такая).

Когда я выставляю все как есть - ничего не работает, когда же прописываю как шлюз DNS сервер все работает.

Это нормально? Должно ли так работать? Что может это означать?

Шлюз поднимаю на баз Endian Firewall Comunity. Не работает=появляется ошибка о невозможности найти ya.ru.

Comment: А можно больше подробностей? Из вашего примера, перва мысль, а какая у вас сеть (сеть/маска)?

Comment: вы про внутреннюю или внешнюю? про внешнюю я все написал что знаю, внутренняя тут никак не влияет на настройки. Маска внешней 255.255.255.248 вроде бы (сейчас нет под рукой, не могу точно всспомнить).

Comment: Хм... при такой маске, ваш внешний адрес должен быть - 20.10.0.1-6 (тогда должны работать со шлюзом), если же ваш адрес - 20.10.1.1-6 (тогда со шлюзом 20.10.0.2 вам никак не связаться).

Comment: Да простите забыл про вой адрес) как раз второй вариант. Я полагаю там маска должна быть 255.255.252.248(если не ошибся)?

Comment: Ошиблись:) 255.255.252.0.
Но для ваших адресов (не знаю, что там у вас еще есть) достаточно вот такой
255.255.254.0

Comment: не знаю может глупый вопрос, но есть разница если *.*.х.* выделенный элемент будет не 0 и 1 как в примере, а например 54 и 53?

Comment: Да не особенно, тогда будет отличаться ваш адрес.
Для маски 255.255.254.0 можно использовать 52 и 53, для 255.255.252.0 - 52, 53, 54 и 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш внешний адрес должен быть - 20.10.0.1-6 (тогда должны работать со шлюзом), если же ваш арес - 20.10.1.1-6 (тогда со шлюзом 20.10.0.2 вам никак не связаться).

255.255.252.0 (20.10.0.1 - 20.10.3.254) 
Но для ваших адресов (не знаю, что там у вас еще есть) достаточно вот такой 255.255.254.0 (20.10.0.1 - 20.10.1.254)

Для маски 255.255.254.0 можно использовать 52 и 53, для 255.255.252.0 - 52, 53, 54 и 55.